# Change variable every each foreach

Tags: php

I have script which takes urls form txt file, goes to page and parse data I need. File looks like:

```
example.com/1.html
example.com/2.html
...
```

I would like to stop use the file, just use example.com/X.html and set max to 150, so my foreach will add +1 to url every time the loop is working - from example.com/1.html to example.com/150.html. This is how it looks like:

```
$plik = file("plik.txt");

foreach($plik as $url)
{

$text = file_get_contents($url);
//my job

}
```

Comment: you just want 150 loops in total?

Comment: Depending to website which I'm working with. Sometimes 150, sometimes 400.

Comment: Simply you can use range() php function.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just repeat the process 150 times:

```
for($i=1;$i<=150;$i++) {
    $url = "example.com/".$i.".html";
    $text = file_get_contents($url);
    // your job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can use [foreach()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [range()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), i.e.:

```
foreach(range(1,150) as $n)
{
    $html = file_get_contents("http://somesite/$n.html");
    # rest of the code
}
```